# TypeScript: ignore function signatures from inherited classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm trying to build an extension system with TypeScript. This system works as long as the extendable classes don't inherit from each other.

Here is a simplified version for this inheritance problem:

```js
class ExtensionHost {
    addExtension(extension: Extension<typeof this>): void {}
}

class Extension<T> {}

class Object3D extends ExtensionHost {}

class Cube3D extends Object3D {}

class CubeExtension extends Extension<Cube3D> {}

class Object3DExtension extends Extension<Object3D> {}

const cubeExt = new CubeExtension();
const objectExt = new Object3DExtension();

const cube = new Cube3D();
const object = new Object3D();

cube.addExtension(cubeExt); // OK
cube.addExtension(objectExt); // Problem 1: should error, but doesn't

object.addExtension(objectExt); // OK
object.addExtension(cubeExt); // Problem 2: should error, but doesn't
```

The class `Object3D` is extendable. And the class `Cube3D` inherits this functionality from the `Object3D`. Yet I want to prevent it from extending any `Extension` that does not directly match its own class.

**Problem 1**: the `cube` should not be extendable with a `Extension<Object3D>`. By hovering over the `cube.addExtension(objectExt)` it gives me the call signature of `Object3D.addExtension(extension: Extension<Object3D>)`.

**Problem 2**: the `object` should not be extendable with `Extension<Cube3D>`. Here it makes a bit more sense, because a `Extension<Cube3D>` is also a `Extension<Object3D>`. Yet it would still be nice to prevent it.

**Question**: Is there a way to type it in a way that those problems can be fixed on the type-level? Problem 2 is not that important.

Comment: [Empty classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and [unused generics](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) behave strangely. You should add structure to your classes and use your type parameters. If your actual code isn't empty like this, then please [edit] to give a [mre] without that issue. But if this *is* how your actual code looks, with empty classes and unused generics, then your problem is explained in the two links above. Which is it, how should we proceed?